# Configuration database version different in 2 farms with same patch history

Tags: update, patching

We are using SP2013 on-premise enterprise edition. We have a development farm and a test farm. Dev farm have one machine as WFE+APP and Test farm have 2 WFE and 2 APP. Both farm have separated SQL server (hence both are not using standalone installation)

We patched both farm with Lumension. Only Windows updates were patched to all servers in 2 farms. No SharePoint CU was applied. After patch, we run the Product Configuration Wizard in both farm and then reboot all servers. Everything have gone through successfully.

However, when we check CA > System Settings > **Servers in Farm**. The Configuration database version is **15.0.4719.1000** in Dev farm while the version is **15.0.4763.1000** in Test farm.

We also checked Upgrade and Migration > **Check product and patch installation status**. No missed patch found. In fact we can find the patch with version number **15.0.4763.1000** in Dev farm's Check product and patch installation status page.

We have checked **Installed Update** in window's control panel as well. Both farm seems have same update installed.

My question is, why the The Configuration database version is STILL **15.0.4719.1000** in Dev farm while the patches 4763 are in place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to the following question is posted here by the questioner: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/61df3b52-a464-4aea-b481-9ca59ae795e8/configuration-database-version-different-in-2-farms-with-same-set-patch-actions?forum=sharepointadmin

> We compare the "Installed update" more carefully and found some updates contain multiple entries. For example, KB123456 shows up 10 times in development farm but 12 times in test farm. That means the KB123456 in development is not exactly same as test farm. We re-install those patches 1 by 1 again and they are in sync now.
>   After they are in sync, we run the Product Configuration Wizard again. Version number are now matching.

Answer (score 1):

This might happen sometimes in exceptional cases like yours. If executing Config Wizard does not update the Config Database, then executing **PSConfig** command via PowerShell is advisable.

To update the SharePoint databases, you must manually run the PSconfig utility. To run the utility:

1. Open command prompt in Administrative mode.
2. Change directory to `C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\15\BIN`
3. Run `PSConfig.exe -cmd upgrade -inplace b2b`

Comment: After 4 config settings completed it return "Configuration of the SharePoint Products has succeeded.". However everything still same as before.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a CU was deployed https://buildnumbers.wordpress.com/sharepoint/

15.0.4763.1000 - October 2015 CU - KB3085492
15.0.4719.1002 - May 2015 CU - KB3039780